# Create SPIdev devices at runtime

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, spi

I have a device with SPI bus which is connected via PCIe to a linux machine. I'm developing a simple SPI driver for this device. With `spi_register_master` I can create a SPI master (it is listed under `/sys/class/spi_master/spixxxx`).

For accessing the bus I would like to use `spidev` from the userland, but I have not found a way to register a `spidev` device at runtime. All ways I have found use the device tree to insert the information into the linux kernel.
Is there some way to create `spidev`devicesat runtime?

Edit: I suppose it is the same problem with all protocol drivers and not limited to `spidev`.

Comment: Which platform? For x86 ACPI based it can be done purely via ACPI. For DT based I supposed via DT overlays.

Comment: It's a ARM based platform (NVIDIA Jetson).

Comment: Use Device Tree (overlays). This the proper way to instant it.

Comment: One snag you may run into with using `spidev` as the SPI client device in the Device Tree is choosing a `compatible` string. `compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";` works even though it is a complete lie! The alternative is to patch "drivers/spi/spidev.c" to add your own `compatible` device ID.

Comment: Another snag is that the mainline Linux kernel doesn't have any standard way to load device tree overlays easily without using a set of kernel patches to load Device Tree Overlays via the ConfigFS interface, for example: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/geert/renesas-drivers.git/log/?h=topic/overlays

Comment: @IanAbbott, What a surprise! I always thought that OF has a clear mechanism how to load DT overlays at runtime.